# Mulitple application under Default website IIS asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have got a space in our company server with url **tools.mysite.com** which is a .net based web application. So its working fine in our domain. But now we have new requirement of setting up a new application under tools.mysite.com which is also a separate web project done in ASP.NET 4.0. Unfortunately I dont have any previous experience of setting up IIS single site with multiple application. But with little googling, I tried creating a **applicaiton** under Default website (tools.mysite.com) and specified the physical location and alias as **downloads**.

So obviously as I expected I am getting that path in browser like this and for testing I put a test.txt file there.

> tools.mysite.com\downloads\test.txt

which is working fine

But the challenge is when I try

> tools.mysite.com\downloads\default.aspx

its triggering an error **resource cannot be found**. But default.aspx is there which is my home page I have created and its loading fine when I run the application from Visual Studio itself.

So please help me to run my second .NET based application.

Comment: So the first .NET web application is not done in ASP.NET 4.0? You also need to post the full information showed in the error page of "resource cannot be found", such as screen shot.

Comment: Thats also in 4.0